# HP Fortify Audit Workbench

Tags: static-analysis, fortify

I am trying to use the HP Fortify Static Code Analyzer to analyze security concerns in a large C application and I have run into various bugs in the software itself that I cannot seem to find any answers to anywhere on the Internet. I am using version 3.4 of the software and running it on a Linux x64 system.

The main bug that I am encountering that makes it very difficult to use this product at all is that in various different places in their Audit Workbench GUI the program will just close for no reason. An example is whenever a pop-up window shows asking you a question and your answer to the question is just to close the pop-up window by either clicking on the close button or the cancel button, the whole program ends instead of returning you back to where you were when you originally got the pop-up. Another example is when I try to open the Rules Editor, either for a new Rule Pack or an existing Rule Pack, the program opens up a progress window with a moving progress bar that sits there and moves for a while but when it is finished, instead of opening up the Rules Editor, the whole program just ends suddenly.

Has anyone out there seen behavior like this? If so, please let me know what I can do about it. Thank you.

Comment: You should contact fortify support about this if you haven't already. This could be a problem with Linux header files causing a segfault with the version of java. I recall coming across this before in AWB on Fedora.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend upgrading to the latest (4.10 at the time of this post) version.  One thing you can do to help diagnose issues is to look at the log files.  These are located in (by default) `[user.home]/fortify/AWB-3.40/log`.

Also, since you are using Linux 64bit, you will want to ensure that AWB isn't trying to access the 32bit JRE at any time.  This can be accomplished by removing `[fortify install root]/jre` and renaming `[fortify install root]/jre64` to `[fortify install root]/jre`.  Some of the tools default to `/jre` and so you can run into issues on Linux 64bit.